# Sending ICS Calendar File by Email Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, calendar, icalendar

When I send a calendar file by email, it appears correctly on recipient's email. When I send same file programmatically, it does not. here is what I do programmatically

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Mail As New MailMessage
    Mail.Subject = "test email"
    Mail.To.Add("someuser@gmail.com")
    'Mail.To.Add("somesender@gmail.com")
    Mail.From = New MailAddress("somesender@gmail.com")
    Mail.Body = "This is a sample email using VB.NET"

    Dim attachment As System.Net.Mail.Attachment
    attachment = New System.Net.Mail.Attachment("C:\Users\x\Downloads\testCalendar.ics")
    Mail.Attachments.Add(attachment)

    Dim SMTP As New SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com")
    SMTP.EnableSsl = True
    'SMTP.DeliveryMethod = SMTP.DeliveryMethod.SpecifiedPickupDirectory
    SMTP.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("somesender@gmail.com", "password")
    SMTP.Port = "587"
    SMTP.Send(Mail)
End Sub
```

here is the content of the test ics file

BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20160930T110000
DTEND:20160930T120000
SUMMARY:Bastille Day Party
LOCATION:123 Main Street, Anahiem CA
DESCRIPTION:THIS IS A TEST DESCRIPTION
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR

Any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely no way to do this using System.Net.Mail as the resulting MIME message content will have the wrong structure. The VCalendar information needs to be contained within a specific MIME part but it will be placed in a separate one and treated as a normal attachment.

I wrote my own SMTP client and MIME message generator specifically to overcome this issue by creating the MIME content exactly as is required. The issue with doing this was that I needed to cater for different security protocols, such as NTLM, which was a pain to code.

You may be able to find a third-party SMTP client that supports the behaviour you require in the nuget gallery.